How to fix singular error of VLE Split in Dymola ClaraPlus library?
I am simply trying to model a simple water split in Dymola from source to 2 sinks. However, the simplest of case seem to not work, and I don't quite know why the problem is singular.
Model File
Model Error Message, Inline code formatting doesn't work well here for some reason
The number of equations across all variable types are the same, and yet it pops out an overconstrained message. Can anyone help in figuring what's wrong?
Varied the mass flow rates and even erased mass flow rate specifications, but still came out to be a singular problem.

The pressure losses inside the split are set to zero for all three pressure losses considered. If you are modeling only the split  with dp=0, there is no equation that calculates how to split the mass flow between the two branches. You have to define a pressure loss model in the split or add pressure losses in the branches afterwards by connecting valves or other component models with a pressure loss.

Solved. Thanks so much.
